# js post complex object to asp.net mvc

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc-3

The data format in js is like:

```
var data = {};
data = {
  orderInfo: {
   time: '2018-04-01',
   phone: '111122223333'
  },
  products: [
  {id: 1, count: 1},
  {id: 2, count: 2} 
  ]
}
```

however when I post it directly using jQuery's ajax() method, the back end cant receive what I posted, But when posted in the format like:

```
var data = {};
data['orderInfo.time'] = '2018-04-01';
data['orderInfo.phone'] = 111122223333;
data['products[0].id'] = 1;
data['products[0].count'] = 1;
data['products[1].id'] = 2;
data['products[1].count'] = 2;
```

the data can be received by back end, what caused this? Any help will be thankful.
ajax code:

```
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        data: data,
        url: '/SaveOrderInfo'
    }).done(function (data, status, request) {

    }).fail(function (err) {

    });
```

simplified back end code

```
namespace balabala {
    [DataContract]
    public class RVOrderViewRqst : IExtensibleDataObject
    {
        public ExtensionDataObject ExtensionData { get; set; }

        [DataMember]
        public RVOrderCustom orderInfo { get; set; }

        [DataMember]
        public IList < RVOrderDetailCustom > products { get; set; }


        public RVOrderViewRqst()
        {
            products = new List<RVOrderDetailCustom>();
        }
    }

    [DataContract]
    public class OrderDetailInfoCustom {
        [DataMember]
        public RVOrderCustom orderInfo { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
        public IList < RVOrderDetailCustom > products { get; set; }

        public OrderDetailInfoCustom()
    {
        products = new List<RVOrderDetailCustom>();
    }
}

[DataContract]
public class RVOrderDetailCustom {
[DataMember]
        public int id { get; set; }
[DataMember]
        public int count { get; set; }
    }

[DataContract]
public class RVOrderCustom {
    [DataMember]
[DataMember]
        public string time { get; set; }
[DataMember]
        public string phone { get; set; }
    }
}
```

It's to complicated for me to understand, and the back end dude cant find the reason.

Comment: Where is the ajax?

Comment: Hi, I just put my ajax code.

Comment: Can you please add the Mvc action code as well as the class definition of the input parameter of this action?

Comment: Hi I put the simplified back end code

Comment: You need to use `data: JSON.stringify(data),` and add the `contentType 'application/json',` option

Answer (score 0):

Try to add `dataType: 'json'`

```
$.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        data: data,
        url: '/SaveOrderInfo',
        dataType: 'json'
    }).done(function (data, status, request) {

    }).fail(function (err) {

    });
```

And you also need to set in BE the header like

`Response.ContentType = "application/json";`
Or

`Response.Headers.Add("Content-type", "application/json");`

Comment: What does response header content type have to do with action getting the request parameter? This is a straight case of router being unable to map the request to an existing method signature. Response and it’s content type come much later in the cycle

Answer (score 0):

Try to add dataType option to ajax call.

`dataType: 'json'`